# Connecting phpmyadmin and BlackBerry application (Eclipse)

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry, jdbc, phpmyadmin

Well long story short, my application needs to connect to the database in the web to collect information about login details and stuffs. I found out that I can use either JDBC or a webservice but the thing is, I dont believe that we can use JDBC in BlackBerry or if we can it would be very complicated, CMIIW so I had to use a webservice. Can anyone please elaborate what should I exactly do? I got the basic concept but completely blank on what to do? Where should I create the webservice and how do I connect it to the BlackBerry application and Phpmyadmin? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server:

1. Install MySQL
2. Install PHP
3. Make a php-script that gets POST- or GET-
   request, connects to MySQL, processes return values and returns xml.

On the device:

1. Connect to the created php-script, make POST- and/or GET- request and process received xml

Comment: How do you returns an xml? And do you connect to the created php-script? That's actually what I am struggling about

Comment: let say you have a server with address: http://www.myserver.com, and you have created a php script in file myscript.php and placed it to the root folder of your server. Address of your php script will be: http://www.myserver.com/myscript.php  When you access this address from your device, you invoke php script that runs on the server. So, you can make POST request to this address to pass parameters to this script from your device, and open InputStream instance in your device app to read the script response (xml).

Comment: Thanks I think I understand the gist of it! Do you know any links that might help me? Like a tutorial perhaps?

Comment: You can find tutorials via google. Just search for "PHP for beginners", "MySQL for beginners", "HTTP for beginners". You will find a lot of links to tutorials and guidelines. Also look at www.blackberry.net/developers for additional documentation related to blackberry development.